# grep -E regex syntax changed?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

A lot of documentation I've read says that the following command should match lines where x appears at least 3 times in a row but no more than 4 times in a row:

```
grep -E {x}\{3,4}
```

E.g. http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/grep/grep_7.html or http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/postini/docs/admin/en/admin_ee_cu/cm_regex.html

Presumably, that means this should return no matches:

```
xxxxx
xxxxxx
```

But I created a testfile with exactly that and running this command

```
grep -o -E [x]\{3,4} testfile
```

returned this output:

```
xxxx
xxxx
```

It's matching both lines. What's going on? This is in the bash shell on Solaris.

Comment: It is true that `[x]\{3,4}` matches only three or four `x` __but__ that regex says nothing about what precedes or follows those matching characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you should always quote the grep expression, as trying to remember what shell does what with what special character is a pain:

```
grep -o -E '[x]{3,4}' testfile
```

Secondly, `grep` will find a minimal match, it's easy like that, so will happily match a 3 or 4 run of `x` in a longer run of `x`s. To prevent this, some sort of boundary condition will be necessary to *not* match a subset of a longer run. A `grep` with PCRE support can use zero-width lookarounds to achieve this:

```
(echo xxx; echo xxxxxx) | grep -P '(?<!x)xxx(?!x)'
```

Comment: Got it. I thought specifying the 3 or 4 run was enough of a boundary condition. What's the point of specifying the upper bound or 4 if it basically just ignores that? The documentation I linked seemed to imply {n,m} matches no more than {m} in a row. But that seems to mean that "xxxxx...x" where n(x's) > m will return m x's. Heh.

Comment: @FasilAlemante it does, it matches no more than m, but once it has matched, it does not check the rest of the line. However, consider `grep -E 'ax{3,4}b`. That will match `axxxb` and `axxxxb` but not `axxxxxb`.